# Using CSS classes as jQuery variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

To my understanding, in `jQuery` you can set a variable then use it later down the line.

```
var x = 2;
function add() {
    x = x + 2;
}
```

In my code, I have a `CSS` class as a variable.

```
var scroll = $('.verticalScrollBar');
function changeScrollBar() {
    ...
    TweenMax.set(scroll, {css:{height:scrollBarHeight+'%'}});
    ...
}
```

However, this does not seem to work. Initially, I thought it might have been a problem with `GSAP TweenMax` so I tried the following code.

```
function changeScrollBar() {
    ...
    TweenMax.set($('.verticalScrollBar'), {css:{height:scrollBarHeight+'%'}});
    ...
}
```

To my surprise this did work. So my question is why does the line of code `TweenMax.set($('.verticalScrollBar'), {css:{height:scrollBarHeight+'%'}});` work but this line of code `TweenMax.set(scroll, {css:{height:scrollBarHeight+'%'}});` does not?

Working example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/t3xjh6jv/4/)

Broken example [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Vusa360/t3xjh6jv/2/)

Comment: I can't get either of your JSFiddle examples to scroll.

Comment: @showdev I apologise. I am yet to include the scroll function. I am currently working on the look and feel

Comment: @showdev If you like I can link you to a finished version when I complete it?

Comment: Oh ok no problem. Just checking.

Comment: In your non-working example, you select `.verticalScrollBar` before that element exists in the DOM. In your working example, you select that element after it exists in the DOM. [TweenMax documentation](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/set/) states that TweenMax accepts a target object, array of objects, or *selector text*; so you can also specify the selector as a string (".verticalScrollBar") instead of passing a jQuery object.

Comment: Urgh. Just to be pedantic: "*To my understanding, in jQuery you can set a variable then use it later down the line.*" This is an understanding of **JavaScript**, which is a **language**. JQuery is a **popular framework** that lets you do many things in that language. JQuery is not, itself, a language and has nothing to do with that very first code sample where you declare a var and refer to it in a function.

Comment: @showdev Ah thank you. I'll keep that in mind in the future

Comment: @Katana314 Fair point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing:

`var scroll = $('.verticalScrollBar');`

To:

`var scroll = '.verticalScrollBar';`

Results in your broken example operating as expected.

.....

Edited (twice now) for an explanation as to why this is happening.

As @Katana314 pointed out, the `var scroll` bit is defining a jQuery object that doesn't exist at this point.  `$(".verticalScrollBar");` doesn't exist until after `changeScrollBar()` is executed.

Using `var scroll = '.verticalScrollBar'` works because you're not declaring a nonexistent jQuery object.  You're simply providing a bit of text, which CAN be matched to the object once it has been created.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why this occurs?

Comment: I would have to hazard a guess as the issue seems to be related to your external resource (TweenMax), but I'll update the above with that guess momentarily.

Comment: JQuery searches the document for matching elements *at the time that you call `$(...)`*. So, if you call it too early, the element might not even have been parsed into the DOM yet.

Comment: Reviewing the code by @Dan and the comment by @Katana314 makes me think @Katana314 is 100% correct.  `verticalScrollBar` doesn't exist at the point that it is set as a variable.